# Vue class binding with strings?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Is there a way to have Vue class binding working with strings?
So for example:

```
<div :class={open: target == 'myString'}></div>
var app = new Vue({
  target: null
})
```

It works when I do it without the quotes

```
<div :class={open: target == myString}></div>
```

but I get the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "myString" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', // the id of the div that you will apply this object on it
  data : {
    target: '',
    myString: '',
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, all I needed was to initialize target: ' ' instead of null. I don't get the warning anymore and code works!